# SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy limit is not working

Tags: logging, log4j2

I have the following setting in my log4j2 xml

```
<Appenders>
        <RollingFile fileName="C:\logs\Fatal.log" filePattern="C:\logs\Fatal-%i.log" name="FatalFile">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}] %-5level %logger{6} - %msg%n"/>
        </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

when my code runs for long duration, there are 7 logs getting created but, after that the log size starts to grow beyond the 10MB limit and becomes very large for all 7 files.

I need to know why there is only 7 files created and how can limit the file size not to grow beyond 10 MB.

Comment: the jar i have in my configurations are: log4j-1.2-api-2.0-beta8.jar, log4j-api-2.0-beta8.jar, log4j-core-2.0-beta8.jar

Comment: This Log4j version is very old. Can you try upgrading to 2.5 or at least 2.3 if you are still on Java 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DefaultRolloverStrategy creates up to 7 archives on the same day. File size growing beyond 10 MB may be a bug in the old version of Log4j 2 you are using.

Since 2.5, Log4j supports a [custom Delete action](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover) that is executed on every rollover.

You can control which files are deleted by any combination of:

1. Name (matching a [glob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) or a [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html))
2. [Age](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/Duration.html#parseCharSequence) ("delete if 14 days old or older")
3. Count ("keep only the most recent 3")
4. Size ("keep only the most recent files up to 500MB")

Users who need even more fine-grained control over which files to delete can specify a script condition using any supported JSR-223 scripting language.

Please check out the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover), it has three full examples that may be useful.

As an aside, note that you can [compress log files on rollover](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies) to make them take up less disk space.

Finally, be careful! There is no way to recover files deleted this way. :-)

Comment: This is a follow up on this. does the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy fails if same log file is used in mutiple sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I observed exactly the same behavior. But after setting the "append" attribute of  to "false", the RollingFile appender behaved as I wanted. Maybe it would be better if the default value of "append" was "false"...

Comment: Append=true is default because it's safer: it won't override your old log file.